# How to organize maps with different symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, layouts

I'm wondering how to handle many map layouts in QGIS that have different symbology?  As I am making layouts and trying to make them jive together (different scales, showing different things) I feel it is incredibly inefficient to set a layout, change the symbology for a different layout, and then when I go back to the previous layout to change something, I have to change the symbology back to what it was?  How can I manage this better?

Comment: If I needed to do this again I would look at Map Themes more closely as answered by J.R.  In the past for layers that differed in layouts,  I duplicated them, then grouped them together with their new symbology for each layout.  Then I could turn a group on or off as needed,  along with using the lock options in the layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Map Themes](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=themes#configuring-map-themes) with this you are able to register the state of each layer (visibility, style used) and give a name to the configuration. Then in layout you may set each map to follow a specific theme.

For this to work effectively you will need to create several style your layer (read [this](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#managing-custom-styles) to get started)

Closely related : [QGIS: Map theme with layer visibility AND style, does it exist?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375785/qgis-map-theme-with-layer-visibility-and-style-does-it-exist)