# QGIS: freeze frames in print layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I need to display two map frames (Geology and slope map) in one single print layout A3 format.
The problem is that, even if the lock button for Geology map frame is checked (Mappa 1), later, when I prepare the slope map frame (Mappa 1), the former geological frame automatically updates showing the same layers and featurese of slope map.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this, in other words to lock definetevely a map layout frame?

Comment: You may also use map theme for this, it's more flexible than locking layer and style for more information https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422827/how-to-organize-maps-with-different-symbology/422833#422833

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you gotta do is click on the checkboxes of "Lock Layers" and "Lock styles for layers" (Red Circle) in the item properties > Layers > Lock Layers and Lock Styles for layers. Don't forget to select the map you want to lock by clicking on it, so you will be able to display the item properties menu (Blue Circle).

[image]