# Why Layer Combinations plugin is not available in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

QGIS "Layer Combinations" plugin is now deprecated. These are its characteristics: Store and restore layer visibilities, foldings and zooms in "combinations". The visibilities can then be dynamically assigned to composer maps.

They say:

> This plugin is deprecated since the functionality was added to core
> QGIS

I work with QGIS 3.18.3 Zurich. Where I can find this functionality?

Answer (score 6):

This core functionality is called themes. You can save a theme and choose a theme from the theme selector icon above the layer tree. You can also have maps in print layouts that display the layers in a particular theme. See https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#layers-panel

See also [QGIS: Map theme with layer visibility AND style, does it exist?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375785/qgis-map-theme-with-layer-visibility-and-style-does-it-exist) and [Changing polygon color depending on visibility of background map in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456216/changing-polygon-color-depending-on-visibility-of-background-map-in-qgis/456220#456220) for how to combine this with styles, i.e. not only change which layers are shown but also how they are displayed.

Comment: I might also add that you can use different style presets in the one layer (rather than having to duplicate and style differently) along with layer visibility in map themes, in this answer I provided here in a shameless link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456216/changing-polygon-color-depending-on-visibility-of-background-map-in-qgis/456220#456220

Comment: @she_weeds, this was exactly what I was referring to in my 2nd paragraph. I've gone and edited my answer to add your link to mine since they cover something very similar but from different angles.