# Apply "META" Map styles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, qml

I often work with the same layers but have to use different styles on them. Is there a way to swap the styles of more layers at once.

Like for example:
I have three layers (roads, building, vegetation). Now I want to apply a "dark"-Style. So i have to apply a style to every single layer (roads_dark.qml, building_dark.qml, vegetation_dark.qml). When i want to switch to another Meta-Style (like light-theme) i have to do this all over again.

I only can save multiple styles on one layer but i still have to go to every layer an switch manually. I have like 50+ layers...

Anyone an idea how i could achive this?

Comment: If e.g. your dark and light styles are saved for each layer as named styles/style presets, then you can create a map theme where all the layers use the 'dark' style, and then another map theme for 'light'. e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375785/qgis-map-theme-with-layer-visibility-and-style-does-it-exist and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456216/changing-polygon-color-depending-on-visibility-of-background-map-in-qgis/456220#456220 . You would need to manually toggle all the layer styles each time you set up a new map theme, but once set up you can switch back and forth.

Comment: If you want an easier way to create the map theme (i.e. not manually toggle the 'dark' named style/style preset for 50+ layers, then do the same again for the 'light' styles), you would need to programmatically generate the map themes with Python, like in this answer (which solves a different problem) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456216/changing-polygon-color-depending-on-visibility-of-background-map-in-qgis/456220#456220